# Remove line separator of listview jquery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am using a listview of Jquery mobile and I want to remove the line separator of each list item in my css. How can I do this? Thank you.

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="panel-list" data-icon="false">
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-t="lateral_menu_option1" onclick="$('.main-panel').panel('close')" class="main-panel-menu-opt">
                    <div class="panel-images-div"><img src="../img/img.png" class="panel-images"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-t="lateral_menu_option2" onclick="$('.main-panel').panel('close')" class="main-panel-menu-opt">
                    <div class="panel-images-div"><img src="../img/img.png" class="panel-images"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-t="lateral_menu_option3" data-t="lateral_menu_option2" onclick="$('.main-panel').panel('close')" class="main-panel-menu-opt">
                    <div class="panel-images-div"><img src="../img/img.png" class="panel-images"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-t="lateral_menu_option4" onclick="$('.main-panel').panel('close')" class="main-panel-menu-opt">
                    <div class="panel-images-div"><img src="../img/img.png" class="panel-images"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-t="lateral_menu_option5" onclick="$('.main-panel').panel('close')" class="main-panel-menu-opt">
                    <div class="panel-images-div"><img src="../img/img.png" class="panel-images"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-t="lateral_menu_option6" onclick="localStorage.setItem('languagegiza', ''); $('.main-panel').panel('close')" class="main-panel-menu-opt">
                    <div class="panel-images-div"><img src="../img/img.png" class="panel-images"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /panel -->
```

[image]

Comment: Do you can copy and paste generated html? As i remember it's just a border, but it's possible there's something else (depends about settings)

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle. we can understand the code from there.

Comment: I have edited my question with my list code

Comment: add css: .ui-listview > li > a.ui-btn {
            border-width: 0;
        }

Answer (score 0):

simply add in your css:

```
.ui-btn-up-c { border:0px;}
```

Comment: yes only this you have add in your css. Try adding `!important` like `.ui-btn-up-c { border:0px !important;}`

Comment: I can´t, not works, the list is inside panel-list class, I have to put .panel-list .ui-btn-up-c {border:0px !important;}?

Answer (score 0):

To remove Line Separator of List View, you can add this style in CSS.

```
.ui-btn-inner
{
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this and just wrote in my css file:

`#listview-main .ui-btn {border:0px}`

Using jQuery 1.11.2 + jQuery Mobile 1.4.5
Note the id selector for listview... this code does not worked without that.